# Are Transmutation spells lost after dismissing or casting Alter Self

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

The description of transmutation spells is

> Transmutation spells change the properties of some creature, thing,
>   or condition.

So if a transmutation spell was cast after an alter self, and then the alter self was dismissed. Is the transmutation spell still active.

In this particular case, I am look at a transmutation spell that affects the eye sight. (The spell is called dragon sight). The spell Alter Self does not affect eye sight, so I am assuming that the transmutation spell is still in affect.

However, what happens if after an alter self, enlarge person was cast. And then the alter self spell was dismissed. What happens to enlarge person?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unless the spell description says otherwise, each spell has its own history.
Spell activation or dismissal doesn't affect other magical effect on the same target.

So, both *dragon sight* and *enlarge person* continue to function after *alter self* expires or has been dismissed.

The transmutation text you cited is a description of the school's thematics: tells us what kind of magical tricks we could find within the transmutation school. It is not specific enough to rule how transmutation spells work as a whole.